# warning: no description found for function print_alphabet

Tags: c

I'm learning c using the Betty style coding

```
#include "main.h"

/**
 * print_alphabet(void) - entry point
 *
 * Description: This function prints the alphabet, in lowercase
 *
 * Return: void
 */

void print_alphabet(void)
{
        char c;

        for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)
        {
                  _putchar(c);
        }
        _putchar('\n');
}
```

Everytime i check my code with betty i keep getting this error message:
1-alphabet.c:11: warning: no description found for function print_alphabet

Comment: Have you tried removing the newline between the comment and the function?

Comment: Please explain: Who is Betty?

Comment: @Chris yes and it's still the same error.

Comment: Seeing that you have no `main()` but do have an `#include "main.h"` I suspect an unusual file structure. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please [edit] to provide that kind of helpful info directly inside your question, along with the MRE.

Comment: @Yunnosch is she [Betty Holberton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betty_Holberton)? Also [The Art of Clean Code: Mastering the Betty Style](https://dev.to/angelotheman/the-art-of-clean-code-mastering-the-betty-style-30mo)

Comment: https://github.com/alx-tools/Betty

Comment: Flames, please. [Edit]. And maybe take the [tour] and read [ask]. The link to Betty github is not bad, but better would be a link to documentation, especially syntax definitions and a [mre], please.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [§2.1 Documentation - Functions](https://github.com/alx-tools/Betty/wiki/Documentation:-Functions), you should not include the argument list in the *function_name* part of the comment.

Additionally, it seems like you should avoid the empty line between the end of the comment and the function.

```
/**
 * print_alphabet(void) - entry point
 *
 * Description: This function prints the alphabet, in lowercase
 *
 * Return: void
 */

void print_alphabet(void)
{
```

should be

```
/**
 * print_alphabet - entry point
 *
 * Description: This function prints the alphabet, in lowercase
 *
 * Return: void
 */
void print_alphabet(void)
{
```

Altering the code in this way satisfies the [`betty-doc`](https://github.com/alx-tools/Betty/blob/master/betty-doc.pl) program.